# Will bash be able to handle folders with the "dollar sign" character ("$")?

Tags: bash, character

Working on a project within a large co. The folder for a project contains the "$" (dollar sign) character. This seems to be confusing bash when I try to change directory to this folder:

```
cd TEST_$_xyz
```

Yields an error:

```
No such file or directory
```

I'm almost sure that this is because of bash's handling of the "$" character, but I'm extremely new to bash, so I'm looking for confirmation before I force a name-change.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the dollar ($) sign like so. Otherwise, it treats `$_xyz` as an environment variable.

```
cd TEST_\$_xyz
```

example:

```
# In this case, $a evaluates to nothing because it is not defined
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf$ mkdir a$a
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf$ ls
a

# Here, I have escaped $ with \ so that it's treated like a normal $ character
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf$ mkdir a\$a
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf$ ls
a  a$a

# changing directory to directory with escaped $ sign
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf$ cd a\$a
me@mypc:~/tmp/asdf/a$a$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose the filename in single quotes - that way there is no variable expansion:

```
cd 'TEST_$_xyz'
```

See the ["Single Quotes" section of the `bash` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
    cd TEST*xyz
```

(An asterix can cope with many different chars, as '$', space and others.)

Comment: That might be OK for interactive use, but not in a script. Since this is a programming site, we should assume scripting (although it might not necessarily be the case here).

Comment: I don't see why this approach could not be used in scripts.

Comment: Because it will match other characters beside `$`. Interactively you might know a priori that there aren't any, but a script shouldn't make  assumptions like that.